Supabase OAuth redirect returning text document
I'm running a react native app using expo on my device and connecting to supabase running locally on my laptop. That connection seems to be working and I'm able to create a user with Spotify OAuth but I seem to get redirected locally to a text document that contains json with my app info and expo data. Any ideas what could be configured incorrectly? Should I run the supabase instance on my laptop's ip address instead of localhost?
I think the issue could be that I'm redirecting back to expo on my laptop instead of the app running on my device?
